# Removing a child div from a parent div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete the child element in the dom from its parent using jquery.

Here is the code snippet.

```
$('#delete').live('click' , function() {

    var strchild = m.split("/",2)[1];
    var c = group.children(strchild);
    c.remove();

});
```

strchild contains the id of the child element. group is the parent object. I am getting the right child element in the variable c. But the remove function fails.

Can some help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, can you include a snippet of html and examples of what "m" may contain (and therefore what strchild may contain by proxy)?

Comment: I have built a tree structure based on the folders and its files. I have programmed the folder names to be id's of the parent div and file names to be the id's of the child div. So m is actually a string which contains the path and so i am splitting it and finding the file name and using it as an id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
strchild
```

as the id of the element you want to remove, you can do

```
$("#" + strchild).remove()
```

assuming it is the only element with that id (it should be, that's the whole point of id).

EDIT:

With multiple ids, you would need to reference the parent specifically. This is very simple, since you say in your question that group is the parent object. This answer assumes it is the object itself, rather than the id, as your code sample implies.

```
$("#" + strchild, group).remove()
```

Adding the second argument here constrains the selector to the specifications of that second argument. So this will search the parent (group) for an element with the id strchild, and then remove that element.

Comment: I have a hierarchical structure where different parents could have children with same id's. In that case, how do i remove the child from its parent.

Comment: @srini I've edited the answer to do this. I do, however, recommend using a distinct id for each element. In this case, if each parent has a distinct id, you could have each child id be of the form "parentid_childid"